# Detect File Input Cleared With jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

I have an html file input field, and I have some jQuery code that detects the height and width of the image the user selects.

I am following the format I found here: http://jsbin.com/oTAtIpA/3/edit?html,css,js,output

The problem I am having is I would also like the upload preview to be cleared if the browse field is cleared.

Specifically, I was testing this on Chrome, and I found that if I browsed for an image for that field, it will populate the image information correctly.  However, if I clicked on the button again to browse for a different file, then hit cancel instead of selecting a file, Chrome will show no file selected, but the upload preview remains.

Is there a way to detect when a file input is cleared so I can clear the upload preview as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it as follows:

```js
$("#file").on("change", function() {
  if ($(this).val()) { return; }
  alert("Input is empty.");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="file" type="file">
```

Comment: Thanks Tim, apparently I was doing it right, I just forgot to write in a check to see if the field was empty.  My mistake!

Answer (score 0):

You need to clear the preview area when the file input is changed to nothing:

```
$("#choose").change(function (e) {
    if(this.disabled) return alert('File upload not supported!');
    var F = this.files;
    if(F && F[0]) {
        for(var i=0; i<F.length; i++) readImage( F[i] );
    } else {
        $('#uploadPreview').empty();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you click a cancel button on file upload dialog box then file length is **0**.

```
var file=document.getElementById("choose");

file.onchange=function(){
   if(file.value.length==0){
       $("#uploadPreview img").attr("src","");
   }
   else{
      //do your other stuff
   }
 }
```